# Replace single string in a pandas dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Pandas column with the path of some pictures like this:

```
http://localhost:8888/view/Desktop/directory1/directory2/john.jpeg
http://localhost:8888/view/Desktop/directory1/directory2/alice.jpeg
http://localhost:8888/view/Desktop/directory1/directory2/joseph.jpeg
...
```

I need to replace `/view/` for `/files/`. Wichi Pandas method do I have to use to iterate and doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `.str.replace`:

```
df['YOUR COLUMN'] = df['YOUR COLUMN'].str.replace('/files/', '/views/')
```

Output:

```
                                                             YOUR COLUMN
0    http://localhost:8888/files/Desktop/directory1/directory2/john.jpeg
1   http://localhost:8888/files/Desktop/directory1/directory2/alice.jpeg
2  http://localhost:8888/files/Desktop/directory1/directory2/joseph.jpeg
```